# SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe is consuming all the memory

Tags: 2010, active-directory

I have many processes with the name SPUCWorkerProcessProxy (over 50 process) that are consuming all the available memory. I guess, this problem appeared after installing Active Directory.

What shall I do to free the RAM?

Comment: Have you seen this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3b50dd8b-d789-4a2d-86f2-784b0e73c6a8/foundation-many-spucworkerprocessproxyexe-processes-and-high-memory-load

Comment: Hi, thanks :)  
I've seen it but i didn't understand.. I've found a solution to stop these processes but it's not the best way I guess. I went to: Administration Tools -> Services -> Sharepoint 2010 User Code Host -> Stop

Any other suggestion or explanation?

Comment: No one knows?!!